# Route command to use wildcard

Tags: wifi, bash, router, network

I have a bunch of routes to my LAN line that won't resolve through my WiFi (which is set as 1st order).

```
sudo route add 10.999.999.999 10.888.888.888
```

I have a lot more but that's just a sample. This works great but sometimes I need access to another Network asset which means I have to go add it to the list again.

Can I make it so I route any IP address starting with 10 gets rerouted through the LAN router?

Something like this:

```
sudo route add 10.* 10.888.888.888
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK

**My Setup:**

I have two internet connections.

1. WiFi - no firewalls - no access to network assets
2. LAN - firewalls - access to network assets

I set WiFi first in my order of precedence and I force certain domains through the LAN connection using my host file to resolve the IP addresses and a routes table to direct those IPs through my LAN router.

Basically I want my cake and eat it too.

---

#### Here is what I ended up with:

```
#! /bin/bash    
sudo route -n flush
sudo route add -net 10 10.255.255.255    
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off    
sleep 2    
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

This flushes the route table, routes any traffic starting with the ip address `10.` to my LAN connection's router, then restarts the wifi router (`en0`).

Comment: the three digit numbers in an IPv4 address only go to 255 not 999. 10.999.999.999 isn't a valid IP address.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't feel right putting in my IP addresses. I suppose I could have commented that these were just placeholder IP addresses but I assumed that was obvious.

Comment: How about bash expansion? You can write something like: `10.{0..255}.{0..255}.{0..255}` It'll expand to all IPs beginning with number 10.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Testing now!

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek 'Argument list too long'

Comment: Your setup seems really broken. Can you try to further explain the topology? Why does it not "resolve through [your] WiFi" and what does that even mean?

Comment: @Hop I added the backstory. Note my setup works fine just looking for a way to do a cleaner routes bash script.

Comment: Your edit explains nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct form to add a net route is

```
route add -net 10 $GW
```

Obviously you have to replace `$GW` with the ip address of your gateway.

Comment: Dang that makes way more sense. 
Thanks for your patience . Obviously I don't know bash scripts at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for` loops. Here's an example:

```
for i in {0..255}; do
    for j in {0..255}; do
        for k in {0..255}; do
            sudo route add 10.$i.$j.$k 10.888.888.888
        done;
    done;
done
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as your expansion comment?

Comment: No It's not, because right now `route` command is run separately for every IP address.

Comment: I guess this answers the question, but 16 million iterations seems a bit overkill.  If I were the asker, I'd go about this another way.

Comment: @jonescb Exactly. Had to stop it a t \*.\*.4.255

Comment: please don't do that

Comment: I suppose this is as close as I am going to get. This answer could help others who could add some specificity to the loops. I.E. 10.100.100.{20..30}

Comment: @jonescb and hop, You're right. I didn't think about how many iterations it would do. 16 million is indeed ovekill.